# HTML/PHP Get more TD's based on array elements

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I am looking if there is a way to add td's/tr's based on the amount of elements i have in my PHP array.

More specifically:
I have 4 arrays that are filled by the amount of numbers in a textdocument (PHP-Script). That works just fine. Then i have my layout coded in HTML which contains a Table where one of the 4 arrays should show all results in the one TD and in the other half of the table are more rows with the rest of the arrays data to work with it.

I want a form to first of show all numbers that are in the array. ff u klick on one number the rest of the data should appear in the other half so you can edit it.

I just cant figure out how to do it. I would probably know how to do it in C# but since im not too experienced in HTML/PHP Im just stuck.

Thats my table at the moment:

```
<table style="padding-top:10px" align=center>
    <tr>
    <?php include ("durchwahl.php"); ?>
        <td rowspan = "6"></td> </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <table> 
                <tr> <td> Durchwahl </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_durchwahl" name="nv_durchwahl"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td> Anzeigename </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_anzeigename" name="nv_anzeigename"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td> Angezeigte Durchwahl </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_anzeigenummer" name="nv_anzeigenummer"> </td> </tr>
                <tr> <td> Passwort </td> <td> <input type="text" id="nv_passwort" name="nv_passwort" > </td> </tr>
                <tr><td><br/></td><td><br/></td></tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="submit" id="nv_speichern" name="nv_speichern" value="Speichern"></td> 
                    <td><input type="submit" id="nv_delete" name="nv_delete" value="L&ouml;schen"> </td> 
                    <td> <input type="submit" id="nv_add" name="nv_add" value="Hinzuf&uuml;gen"> </td></tr>
            </table> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my code to get the Array from my Database (the file is called sip_tabelle.php):

```
$dw = [];
$result =mysql_query("SELECT durchwahl FROM sip");  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$dw[] = $row;
}
```

And with this i try to fill out my TD's (Thanks to Guilherme Ferreira).

```
<table>
<?php include("./sip_table.php"); 
foreach($dw as $reihe):?>
<tr>
<?php foreach($reihe as $k=>$zelle):?>
<td><?php echo $zelle ?></td>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

It now posts each entry of the database, but twice. So I have 2 TD's with the same entry.

Any Ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: please be more specific and add some Source Code to your question - otherwise no one here on stackoverflow will be able to answer your question.

Comment: *" is a way to add td's/tr's based on the amount of elements i have in my PHP array?"* Yes, there is a way. Please share what you have tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, VitaminAqua! You have to **add more details** and to **show relevant code.**  **You can edit questions using ‘edit’ link below tags list.** Please see **“[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”** for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic PHP and i saw some guy just down voted you.
But i think that if you're learning there is nothing wrong with a "dummmy" question.
So
If your array is like this

```
$a = array(
    array('somevalue1','anothervalue1','evenother1'),
    array('somevalue2','anothervalue2','evenother2'),
    array('somevalue3','anothervalue3','evenother3')
);
```

Then its easy

```
<table>
<?php foreach($myarray as $row):?>
   <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['some_key_1'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['some_key_2'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['some_key_3'] ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

OR also if you want to have automatic td's

```
<table>
<?php foreach($myarray as $row):?>
   <tr>
        <?php foreach($row as $k=>$cell):?>
        <td><?php echo $cell ?></td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

If you see it's possible to have php loops inside html just like you do in MVC6 templates on C#. You can have any php instruction inside html directly.

On my example there is a foreach giving me the objects from an array just like C#

Comment: I did this and it worked just fine :)
Thanks a lot. 

But i have a problem. the numbers are twice on the form.
So its like

101 101
102 102

And i actually only want it once. Used your second template.
Any guess why it could be like that?

Comment: If your array is comming from database than it could be the way you are fetching the rows. for example, if you are using mysql and mysql_fetch_assoc it will create an array with two times each cell

Comment: Did so, hope you can do something with it.

Comment: @VitaminAqua as i said, your problem is that you are using mysql_fetch_array. Instead use mysql_fetch_assoc. This way you will have only one row for each result